# AWS /dev/xvda or /dev/sda1 wont mount as root

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-key-pair

Followed this to replace key pair
Went to reattach drive as root at /dev/xvda 
 a as well as /dev/sda1 and it still won't mount as root filesystem
Everywhere I've read States it's one or the other, is there any other possibilities?

Edit: For some strange reason the drive will mount to root on new instance but not the old one.

Comment: See what AMI your instance used and run a new instance from the same AMI with the same instance type. Then just look at the drive signature on the new instance.

Comment: That was it man, thought they were the same AMI running, this one mounts at just xvda, thanks